# Nonlinear first order ODE with quadratic in the derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics, nonlinear-system

This equation shouldn't be so hard, and yet I'm stymied.

$$
\left( \frac{dw}{dz} \right )^2 + \alpha \frac{dw}{dz} + w \beta = 0
$$
with $w(0) = w_0>0$ $w(L) = 0$ for some known L and $\alpha(z)>0$ and $\beta(z)>0$ known. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ actually begin life as functions of known $w$, so I dont worry about existence of solution, what I want to prove is that I can invert back from $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to give unique $w$. $d \alpha / dz = \beta + C$ for some constant $C$ if it helps.

I can solve for some special cases but I'm interested in a general expression, or at least to prove uniqueness. Interestingly, those special cases are not unique if I just put constraint at $z=0$ but become so with the $z=L$ constraint.

Comment: You may check a book "odinary ODE" by Ince.

Comment: Hey, Ince is online... I would not have expected that. Ploughing through now.... https://archive.org/details/ordinarydifferen029666mbp

Comment: Do you really mean that "α and β actually begin life as known functions of w"?

Comment: Yes..... Actually that is correct. In the real world, w is the velocity of fluid and $\alpha = \theta - Cz$ and $\beta = \theta^\prime$ are measurable parameters from the flow. So then in the real world, we can consider measuring $\theta$ to get $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and that as to give a way of computing $w$.

Comment: Ince seems to be proposing a Taylor expansion of those square roots and writing the answer as infinite sum. Not the most satisfying solution...

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$$\left( \frac{dw}{dz} \right )^2 + \alpha(z) \frac{dw}{dz} + w \beta(z) = 0$$

We obtain:

$$\frac{dw}{dz}=-\frac{1}{2}\alpha(z)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha^2(z)-4w \beta(z)\right)^{1/2}......(1)$$

$$\frac{dw}{dz}=-\frac{1}{2}\alpha(z)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha^2(z)-4w \beta(z)\right)^{1/2}......(2)$$

You might be integrate (1) and (2) to find $w(z)$.

EDIT:

Not quite yet.

$w(z)$ appeared in the square root.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For the application at hand, I can prove that the term in the integrand is positive, but not strictly positive. It will touch zero. This means (I think) that I dont get even a simple proof that each of these ODE's has a unique solution as the square root is not Lipschitz at the zero.

Comment: Touching zero is fine.  If $\alpha(z)=A(w(z))$ and $\beta(z)=B(w(z))$, then it will help.

Comment: No obvious inversion to get back from w(z). In the formula, $\theta$ will be measured data and $C$ a known constant. $$\left( \frac{dw}{dz} \right )^2 + (\theta(z) - Cz) \frac{dw}{dz} + w \frac{d \theta}{dz} =0 $$